# Using Webflux, is it possible to use AOP to get ServerHttpRequest for logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-aop

Previously my gateway system is created using spring boot `spring-boot-starter-web` && `rest template` (blocking).

Now I want to change to use Webflux as reactive seems more suitable for my case. [Performance Reference](https://filia-aleks.medium.com/microservice-performance-battle-spring-mvc-vs-webflux-80d39fd81bf0)

Previously I'm using AOP for logging `HttpServletRequest` with a `Filter` && `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. For example:

```
RequestAttributes ra = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
ServerHttpRequest servletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) ra).getRequest();
String xForwardedFor = servletRequest.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
String remoteAddress = StringUtils.isBlank(xForwardedFor) ? servletRequest.getRemoteAddr() : xForwardedFor;
```

My question is: **is it possible to use AOP to get `ServerHttpRequest` for logging ?**

I've read [this article](https://azizulhaq-ananto.medium.com/how-to-handle-logs-and-tracing-in-spring-webflux-and-microservices-a0b45adc4610) and I believe it's not enough for my case e.g. logging client address.

Thanks so much && let me know if need more info.

Comment: Hello @vincent-tang I'm facing the same problem. Have you encountered any solution?

Comment: @Merch0 sadly no, I can't find any solution on only using Webflux. I've decided to use both `spring-boot-starter-web` && `spring-boot-starter-webflux` at this moment. In AOP, use the same method to get the servlet request, and after ProceedingJoinPoint proceed, subscribe if value instanceof `Flux` or `Mono`. This should work .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
`ServerHttpRequest` can be used to get the client address and then you can just log it.
I don't have an example for this with AOP, but here is how the IP can be logged:

```
@GetMapping()
public Mono<Employee> receiveMono(ServerHttpRequest request) {
    log.info(request.getRemoteAddress().toString());
    ...
```

If you can get the client address regularly, you can get it also with AOP.

In my German blog I wrote some articles around Spring reactive:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2021/02/webflux.html

Comment: One of the main reason in using AOP is because my case is not possible to add `ServerHttpRequest request` in every incoming HTTP request methods. Sorry as my question seems let people misunderstanding.